# Desktop on external monitor too small

Tags: kde, multi-monitor

I am using Manjora with KDE and recently connected an external monitor to my laptop. Since the laptop has a moderately high DPI (2560x1440) I am forced to use KDE with scaling set to 2. This, on the other hand, looks horrible on the external monitor which is considerably bigger but has less pixels (1920x1200). To fix this, I followed the solution that the user artem suggested to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens?newreg=f22c7551841b4f6a96399f57d056641c. I adjusted the values that needed adjusting which for me resulted in the following two commands:

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1200 --fb 3840x3840 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1x1 --pos 640x2400
```

It works quite well for the most part with one caveat: The desktop on the second monitor is restricted to the upper left quadrant. However, other than what other people in the linked thread reported, I am able to use the full monitor to place windows, move the cursor etc. It is not an issue of the wallpaper not scaling correctly either since I can only right click to get the normal context menu on clicking on the desktop background when I am in the quadrant that actually displays the background. Additionally, the menu button with the 9 dots in a square is also displayed in the top right corner of this quadrant, so now it is sitting pretty much dead center on the upper screen. It seems to me that it is only the second desktop itself that was scaled wrongly. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem with KDE on Arch. A workaround I found is to disable the output to the external monitor right before calling xrandr again with the desired scaling settings. For some reason, when doing this I correctly get the Plasma desktop full-size on the external monitor.

What follows is the command I use, you can probably adjust it with values that work for your setup (`DP-1` is the external monitor, `eDP-1` the laptop lid monitor):

```
# This line turns off the external monitor
xrandr --output DP-1 --off

# This turns the external monitor back on, and gives settings for both monitors
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 \
       --output DP-1 --auto --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP-1
```

Comment: That does the trick for me - thanks a lot for your help.